# Jquery adding json data to html table

Tags: python, jquery

I need to retrieve some data from MySQL database using Flask application and post it to the HTML table using Jquery.
Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/getTerm')
def getTerm():
    try:
        if session.get('user'):
            _userID = session.get('user')
 
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM terms")
            conn.commit()
            terms = cursor.fetchall()
 
            terms_dict = []
            for item in terms:
                item_dict = {
                        'Id': item[0],
                        'Name': item[3],
                        'Definition': item[2],
                        'Status': item[1],
                        'User': item[4]}
                terms_dict.append(item_dict)
 
            return json.dumps(terms_dict)
        else:
            return render_template('error.html', error = 'Unauthorized Access')
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html', error = str(e))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Here is JS and HTML:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/getTerm',
            type : 'GET',
            success: function(res){
                var tr = $('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
        .attr('class', 'name'),
        $('<td>')
        .attr('class', 'definition'),
        $('<td>')
        .attr('class', 'user'),
        $('<td>')
        .attr('class', 'status'));
                                
                
                
                var termObj = JSON.parse(res);
                var term = '';
                var td = $('<td>')
                
                $.each(termObj, function(index, value){
                    term = $(tr).clone();
                    $(term).find('td').text(value.Name);
                    $(term).find('td').text(value.Definition);
                    $(term).find('td').text(value.User);
                    $(term).find('td').text(value.Status);
                    $('.terms').append(term);
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

    <div class="main-terms">
        <div class="main-terms_buttons">
            <button><a href="/showAddTerm">Add term</a></button>
            <button><a href="/showAssigned">Assigned to me</a></button>
        </div>
        <div class="main-terms-table">
            <table class="terms">
            <tr>
                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Definition</th>
                <th>Assigned to</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However in the web page I get the table where the value for 'status' is displayed in all cells. Could you please suggest what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jquery code you are appending all td at onces and you have use `.find('td')` without any other selector so that's why its targetting all tds and changing values.
Instead  target only td where you need to add values i.e :

```
 //add to required tds using class..
    $(term).find('td.name').text(value.Name);
    $(term).find('td.definition').text(value.Definition);
    $(term).find('td.user').text(value.User);
    $(term).find('td.status').text(value.Status);
    $('.terms').append(term);
```

Comment: Glad i helped :) you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)